# "Report a message (Something else)" text box incorrect character count

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, jobs-messages

When trying to report a message sent from a recruiter I'm told that:

> *Your description is too long. Please use at most 255 characters on it.*

Here's a screenshot and you can see that I've only used 252 out of 255 characters.

[image]

If I copy and paste the same text into Notepad and save as plain old ANSI the size of the file is in fact 257 bytes.

Perhaps carriage returns aren't being counted properly. I've not had time to poke around the javascript to see where the wheels are coming off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While [jQuery strips the carriage return when calling .val()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8601601/920295), it keeps it (or adds it on some browsers) when doing an ajax post.

To keep it consistent (we're storing the carriage returns on the database everywhere) what I did was updating the client side code (so that on a newline, it counts it as 2 characters).

Thanks for the report, and sorry for the delay!